# Error TS6200 & Error TS2403: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to set up a node project in typescript.

Two files causing errors :

1. node_modules@types\mongoose\index.d.ts
2. node_modules\mongoose\index.d.ts

[image: 1]

node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:79:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentDefinition, FilterQuery, UpdateQuery, NativeError, Mongoose, CastError, ConnectionOptions, Collection, Connection, disconnected, connected, connecting, disconnecting, uninitialized, Error, QueryCursor, VirtualType, Schema, SchemaTypeOpts, Subdocument, Array, DocumentArray, Buffer, ObjectIdConstructor, Decimal128, Map, Aggregate, SchemaType, Document, ModelUpdateOptions

79 declare module "mongoose" {

```
node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts:1:1
 1 declare module "mongoose" {
   ~~~~~~~
 Conflicts are in this file.

node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts:226:14 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'SchemaTypes' must be of type 'typeof Types', but here has type 'typeof Types'.

226   export var SchemaTypes: typeof Schema.Types;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 38):

Mongoose includes TypeScript types since `mongoose@5.11.0`, so you can remove the package `@types/mongoose`.

Source: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/schema-error-while-running-backend-server-nestjs-angular/12440/3

Comment: Thank you! This answer saves me a lot!

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same issue and fixed it by adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to my `tsconfig.json`. So I didn't have to downgrade Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

nevermind
I downgraded mongoose by running 'npm i mongoose@5.10.19', it worked

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a solution and the points above did not help, uninstalling `@types/mongoose-unique-validator` solved my build errors.